# How to find full gamma function from the result?

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I have a data set and fitted this data as a gamma distribution in R.
Below is me code and result:

```
library(MASS)
y = fitdistr(x,densfun = "gamma")
str(y)

List of 5
 $ estimate: Named num [1:2] 11.222 0.331
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "shape" "rate"
 $ vcov    : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.50532 0.0149 0.0149 0.00046
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "shape" "rate"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "shape" "rate"
 $ loglik  : num -1792
 $ n       : int 484
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "fitdistr"
```

I think shape parameter is 11.222 (alpha) and rate is 0.331 (1/theta), but I want to find the denominator in order to make full gamma function.

[image]

Comment: To get the parameters: `coef(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking how to evaluate a gamma function. There is a function for this in R called `gamma`.

Also, when people refer to a rate parameter instead of a scale parameter, they usually mean the parametrization:

$$f(x;\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x\beta}$$

Comment: I used gamma() and feed the shape parameter (11.222). This returned  "shape 6129728" Is this correct answer for the denominator?